# Difference in specifying component as tag or as an attribute

Tags: angular, angular-components

Let's say there is an Angular component with `selector: 'my-component'`.
It is possible to do the both ways:

```
<div><my-component/></div>
```

and

```
<div my-component></div>
```

Is there any difference in rendering or component behavior? If no then why we have 'attribute' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selector: 'my-component'` precisely means that you want to use a `my-component` element for the component.

If you want to use an attribute, use `[my-component]`.

If you want to be able to use both, use `my-component,[my-component]`.

The selector is a CSS selector, just like the CSS selectors you would use in a CSS file. They're more restricted, but the syntax is the same.